# And operator in VB

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to program some VB code to display an error message if someone selects an licensing option from a drop down menu but does not indicate a quantity.

When they select the licensing option, it populates a cell with a defined name of FSValue . Right next to that is another cell to specify the quantity, called FSQuantity. The default value for FSValue is blank (empty), and the default value for FSQuantity is zero.

If they select an option from the dropdown menu and populate the FSValue cell, but do not indicate a quantity, I would like to display an  error message.

This is the code I am trying to use (I have tried several iterations of this, using both the defined cell names and cell locations):

```
If (FSValue = "") And (FSQuantity = 0) Then
     MsgBox ("Please Enter a Value Quantity")
     Range("F47").Select
     Exit Sub
End If
```

I've also tried with nested if statements such as:

```
If FSValue = "" Then
    If FSQuantity=0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please Enter a Quantity")
        Range("F47").Select
        Exit Sub
    End if
End if
```

Nothing is working and it doesn't seem like it should be that difficult. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it VBA or VB? If you want VBA, please title acordingly. If you want VB, please change your tags accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> If they select an option from the dropdown menu and populate the FSValue cell, but do not indicate a quantity, I would like to display an error message.

```
FSValue = ""
```

Look at those things together. At this point, they have selected a value. `FSValue` is no longer blank. You want this:

```
FSValue <> ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wrap your tests in an NZ function,

If Nz(FSValue,"") = "" Then
    If Nz(FSQuantity,0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please Enter a Quantity")
        Range("F47").Select
        Exit Sub
    End if
End if

Comment: Excel VBA doesn't have a `Nz` function - that would be Access VBA.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I should have realized by the code sample it was Excel VBA.